# How to change package name in multi module project with firebase in android(java) app?

Tags: java, android, xml

It gives package error while changing package name in module

i tried to change in packagename in one module but it gives me error package R not found, I am expecting to change package name in one module in multi module app

Answer (score 0):

Rename package name using shift+f6,

then ctrl + shift + r then replace old package name with new one

if firebase is integrated,

Replace package name in google-services.json

then, restart or invalidate caches